# Sails - Client sockets do not seem to broadcast changes

Tags: rest, socket.io, sails.js, postman, sails.io.js

i dived into Sails recently and have a basic tool running. However only partially. I subscribed to changes on a model called 'job'. But i only get a message, when i PUT, POST or DELETE via Postman, but not when i use the browser's io.socket itself.

My subscription:

```
io.socket.on('connect', function connected() {
  io.socket.on('job', function jobReceived(message) {
    console.log("Got job", message);
  });
});
```

My browser based create:

```
io.socket.post("/job", {uuid: 'someuuid', ..... }, function(data, err){
  console.log(data||err);
  io.socket.publishCreate(data.uuid); // Thought this might help, but is not defined.
});
```

Once i refreshed the page my browser-based created data was also there, so it was stored, but did not fire a message.

**EDIT:**

When using angular's $http.post(...) it works and sends a message. It HAS to have something to do with the sockets...

How comes that Postman/Angular fires a message and io.socket does not?

**EDIT2:**

I do the GET in a different spot in the app. As I can receive any updates directly emitted from the Sails server I do not think my subscription is the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
io.socket.on('connect', function connected() {
    // Subscribe using Socket.GET
    io.socket.get('job');
    io.socket.on('job', function jobReceived(message) {
        console.log("Got job", message);
    });
});
```

Docs for this [Sails.js Resourceful PubSub](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub)

Comment: I should have mentioned, that I did the GET in a different spot in the app. As i can receive any updated directly emitted from the Sails server I do not think my subscription is the problem in this case, but thanks anyways. I will update my question accordingly